# How to make an image fall partly of the screen without adding a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image I want to have come out of the website from the left and right side. See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meWNk.png)  for what I have so far.

I managed to get it to work by giving the div the image on the left is in a position absolute and a left of -30px, but when I do the opposite for the image on the right (aka position:absolute and right:-30px), the image doesn't get cut off like it does on the right side.

Instead, the page get wider to have space for the image on the right. I have no idea as to how to get this to work and I also don't really know how to word this issue and my searches have come up barely anything to do with what I'm trying to find.

Below the HTML for both sides:

```
  <div class="imgdecalleft">
  <img src="images/img/patroon.svg" alt="patroon">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgdecalright">
  <img src="images/img/patroon.svg" alt="patroon">
  </div>
```

---

And the subsequent CSS:

```
.imgdecalleft {
width: 15%;
position: absolute;
left: -30px;
}
.imgdecalright {
width: 15%;
position: absolute;
right: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that, but I've already tried adding overflow and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh nevermind! I misread your code. That fixed it! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: I'd be careful with this. If your user has a narrow screen (mobile or resized window) and the rest of your page contents don't fit horizontally they wont be able to scroll to see actual page content.

Comment: Yeah, I made it so the side images disappear on smaller screens so they don't get in the way of anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach that relies on setting the image width to the width of the container div and then offsetting the image inside the container. Using overflow in this case only effects these divs and their images.

This should still allow the page to be scrollable horizontally on narrow screens.

```css
.imgdecalleft {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imgdecalleft img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}

.imgdecalright {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imgdecalright img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgdecalleft">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/01/15/47/abstract-20445_960_720.jpg" alt="patroon">
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgdecalright">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/01/15/47/abstract-20445_960_720.jpg" alt="patroon">
</div>
```